# I am trying to changing one column based on value

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

```
<?php
include './PHP/serverconn.php';
include './PHP/login.php';
$itemid = '';
$sql = "SELECT id, ItemName, ItemBarcode, CompanyName, OurBarcode, DetailsOnItem, barcodeimg, count, combindedBarcode, modelnumber FROM items";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $itemid = $row['id'];    
  ?>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >
      <th> <?php echo $row['id']; ?></th>
      <td data-column='ItemName' id="ItemName"><?php echo $row['ItemName']; ?></td>
      <td data-column='ItemBarcode' id="ItemBarcode"><?php echo $row['ItemBarcode']; ?></td>
      <td data-column='CompanyName' id="CompanyName"><?php echo  $row['CompanyName']; ?></td>
      <td data-column='OurBarcode' id="OurBarcode"><?php echo $row['OurBarcode']; ?></td>
      <td data-column='DetailsOnItem' id="DetailsOnItem"><?php echo $row['DetailsOnItem']; ?></td>
      <td data-column='DetailsOnItem' id="DetailsOnItem"><?php echo $row['modelnumber']; ?></td>
      <td data-column='barcodeimg' id="barcodeimg" class='warning'><image src='<?php echo $row['barcodeimg']; ?>'></img></td>
      <td data-column="count" 
    class="<?=($row['count'] > 10 ? 'alert-danger' : 'alert-success');?>" 
    id="count"> 
      <?php echo $row['count']; ?>
 </td> 
      <td data-column='combindedBarcode' id="combindedBarcode"><?php echo $row['combindedBarcode']; ?></td>
    <td>
    <?php if($_SESSION['admin'] > 0){?>

<div class='btn-group'>
    <button type='sumbit' name='edit' class='btn btn-sm btn-secondary' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-large" >
        <i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>
    </button>
    <a type='sumbit' name='delete' id='delete' href='/delete.php?id=<?php echo $itemid; ?>&logged_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['admin']; ?>' class='btn btn-sm btn-secondary' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete'>
        <i class='fa fa-times'></i>
    </a>
</div>
<?php ;} else { ?>
  <div class='btn-group' disabled>
    <button type='sumbit' name='edit' class='btn btn-sm btn-secondary'  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-large">
        <i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>
    </button>
    <a type='sumbit' name='delete' id='delete' href='/delete.php?id=<?php echo $itemid; ?>&authed=<?php echo $_SESSION['admin']; ?>' class='btn btn-sm btn-secondary' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete' disabled>
        <i class='fa fa-times'></i>
    </a>
  <?php ;} ?>
    </td>  
    </tr> 
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  
  <?php } else { 
    echo 'No results found';
  }
  


$conn->close();

?>
```

if that product is getting low then will change color to red but its doing the whole column if that makes sense I just wanna do one row out of the column.

I am only trying to change the $row[count] trying to change single column based on the count. If count is under 10 then it will change to red. if not nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

if your table displays multiple rows please share the query and the source code of the foreach, anyway i see lot of problem in your code:

1. `<image>` tag does not exist in html and it does not need a closing tag, the correct format: `<img src="" />`
2. you make the alert table td in one line:

```html
<td data-column="count" 
    class="<?=($row['count'] > 10 ? 'alert-danger' : 'alert-success');?>" 
    id="count"> 
      <?php echo $row['count']; ?>
 </td>
```

3. if you want to color the whole row :

```php
<tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" 
    class="<?=($row['count'] > 10 ? 'alert-danger' : 'alert-success');?>" >
```

Comment: I update what I upload hope that helps a little more. I tried both of those none of them worked.

Comment: your code is ok, but you dont fix the image and please remove the `<tbody>` tag. i didn't get an answer if you want to color only the given cell or the whole row ?

Comment: Never mind I fixed it I was back words on the bigger than greater than lmao

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include './PHP/serverconn.php';
include './PHP/login.php';
include 'InventoryPages\testingautoupdate.php';
$itemid = '';
$sql = "SELECT id, ItemName, ItemBarcode, CompanyName, `Location`, DetailsOnItem, barcodeimg, count, combindedBarcode, modelnumber FROM items";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $itemid = $row['id'];    
    $count =$row['count'];
      ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >
      <th scope="row"> <?php echo $row['id']; ?></th>
      <td data-column='ItemName' id="ItemName"><?php echo $row['ItemName']; ?></td>
      <td data-column='ItemBarcode' id="ItemBarcode"><?php echo $row['ItemBarcode']; ?></td>
      <td data-column='CompanyName' id="CompanyName"><?php echo  $row['CompanyName']; ?></td>
      <td data-column='Location' id="Location"><?php echo $row['Location']; ?></td>
      <td data-column='DetailsOnItem' id="DetailsOnItem"><?php echo $row['DetailsOnItem']; ?></td>
      <td data-column='DetailsOnItem' id="DetailsOnItem"><?php echo $row['modelnumber']; ?></td>
      <td data-column='barcodeimg' id="barcodeimg" class='warning'><img src='<?php echo $row['barcodeimg']; ?>'/></td>
      <?php if($count < 10) {echo "<td data-column='count' class='alert-warning' id='count'> $count </td> ";}else{echo "<td data-column='count' class='alert-success' id='count'> $count </td> ";}?>
      <td data-column='combindedBarcode' id="combindedBarcode"><?php echo $row['combindedBarcode']; ?></td>
    <td>
    <?php if($_SESSION['admin'] > 0){?>

<div class='btn-group'>
    <button type='sumbit' name='edit' class='btn btn-sm btn-secondary' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal<?php echo $itemid;?>" >
        <i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>
    </button>
    <a type='sumbit' name='delete' id='delete' href='/delete.php?id=<?php echo $itemid; ?>&logged_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['admin']; ?>' class='btn btn-sm btn-secondary' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete'>
        <i class='fa fa-times'></i>
    </a>
</div>
<?php ;} else { ?>
  <div class='btn-group' disabled>
    <button type='sumbit' name='edit' class='btn btn-sm btn-secondary'  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal<?php echo $itemid;?>">
        <i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>
    </button>
    <a type='sumbit' name='delete' id='delete' href='/delete.php?id=<?php echo $itemid; ?>&authed=<?php echo $_SESSION['admin']; ?>' class='btn btn-sm btn-secondary' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete' disabled>
        <i class='fa fa-times'></i>
    </a>
  <?php ;} ?>
    </td>  
    </tr> 
    <?php include 'InventoryPages\updatemodel.php';
} ?>
  <?php } else { 
    echo 'No results found';
  }
  

$conn->close();

?>
```

Its all fixed it was me not paying attention to thing signs I was using.

Comment: Answers should contain some explanation of the solution. See [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).